# WebRTC - Change audio output device

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I have an application that use user media devices and I would like to allow users to change thereself the audio output. To do that, I followed [this example](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/)

And try to do that when I select the device that I want :

```
var deviceId = "b6d4b95564be24f8be5b8e982fdf851e658a05bb9d3aeec09280976b11debc2a";
var audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
if (typeof audioElement.sinkId !== 'undefined') {
    audioElement.setSinkId(deviceId)
        .then(function() {
            console.log('Success, audio output device attached: ' + deviceId);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            var errorMessage = error;
            if (error.name === 'SecurityError') {
                errorMessage = 'You need to use HTTPS for selecting audio output ' + 'device: ' + error;
            }
            console.error(errorMessage);
        });
} else {
    console.warn('Browser does not support output device selection.');
}
```

`audioElement` is the audio tag in the HTML file.
`deviceId` is the id of the device that I want to use as output (*ex : b6d4b95564be24f8be5b8e982fdf851e658a05bb9d3aeec09280976b11debc2a*)

But this give me an **`DOMException error : Requested device not found`**.

However the `deviceId` result of the `enumerateDevices` function :

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function(devices){
    var audioInputList = _.filter(devices, function(device){ return device.kind == "audioinput"; });
    var audioOutputList = _.filter(devices, function(device){ return device.kind == "audiooutput"; });
}).catch(function(){
    console.log("error");
});
```

So what is wrong?

**EDIT**

This is how I getUserMedia and devices list :

```
function handleSuccess(stream){
    var audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
    audioElement.srcObject = stream;
    return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
}

function gotDevices(devices){
    var audioDevice = { input:[], output:[] };
    audioDevice.input = _.filter(devices, function(device){ return device.kind == "audioinput"; });
    audioDevice.output = _.filter(devices, function(device){ return device.kind == "audiooutput"; });
}

function start(contraints){
    deconnectPeerConnection();
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(contraints).then(handleSuccess)
    .then(gotDevices).catch(handleError);
}
start(constraints);
```

Comment: Do you perform `naviagtor.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` and `.setSinkId()` calls within `.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` call? For the permissions to be granted to set the `sinkId`?

Comment: @guest271314 no, I have already do the `getUserMedia()` function. I do that after, when the user choose the device in a select list.

Comment: Whrere is `deviceId` defined at `audioElement.setSinkId(deviceId)`? Why do you not call `.setSinkId()` within `.then()` chained to `.enunerateDevices()` call?

Comment: @guest271314 deviceId is the value of the select, when I choose it. But to be more clear here, I edit and add it at the beginning of the code I have post. That exactly the value I have.

Comment: The call to `.enumerateDevices()` needs to be chained to `.getUserMedia()` call https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/js/main.js. Both calls are asynchronous

Comment: @guest271314 just try, and it's the same error... Just edit my post to add how I get user media and devices.

Comment: Try running both the same `html` and `javascript` at linked site

Comment: @guest271314 I found the problem, the code above works good... Thanks for your suggestions ;)

Comment: @Berserk what was the issue? I'd encourage posting your findings as an answer to this question for posterity.

Comment: Also, you should check if MediaStream, played by this media element, has an audio track, otherwise an exception is fired.